# Google Maps not working in IE7

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, internet-explorer-7

The following Google map (api v.3) works fine in all browsers except IE7, seems like a simple map. Can anyone help? Many thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/BQzLq/3/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the map option you must remove the last `,`, before the `});`

```
scrollwheel: false,
zoomControl: true,
mapTypeControl: false
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jorge, I knew it was something stupid like this!